# Is there a way to tell the Rust compiler to call drop on partially-initialized array elements when handling a panic?

Tags: arrays, rust, initialization

I'm working on a custom type where I have the following requirements:

1. A collection of elements that avoid heap allocation. I am using arrays instead of a `Vec`.
2. The collection contains non-copyable types
3. Implements `Default` for types that also implement `Default`
4. Implements `From` so that I can build it straight from an array

My biggest problem is implementing `Default` in a safe and useful way.  Being able to support movable types in the array has provided some challenges.  Initially I blindly used `mem::uninitialized()` followed by a for loop of `ptr::write(&mut data[index], Element::default())` calls to initialize it, but I found that if the `default()` call of the individual elements ever panicked, then it would try to call `drop` on all of the uninitialized data in the array.

My next step involved using the nodrop crate to prevent that. I now no longer call `drop` on any uninitialized data, but if any of the elements do happen to panic on `default()`, then the ones before it which were correctly built never call `drop` either.

Is there is any way to either tell the Rust compiler it is safe to call `drop` on the previous array elements that were correctly built or is there a different way to approach this?

To be clear, if one of the individual calls to `Element::default()` panics, I want:

1. Uninitialized elements do not call `drop`
2. Properly initialized elements do call `drop`

I'm not sure it is possible based on what I have read so far, but I wanted to check.

This code shows where I am at:

```
extern crate nodrop;

use nodrop::NoDrop;

struct Dummy;
impl Drop for Dummy {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("dropping");
    }
}
impl Default for Dummy {
    fn default() -> Self {
        unsafe {
            static mut COUNT: usize = 0;
            if COUNT < 3 {
                COUNT += 1;
                println!("default");
                return Dummy {};
            } else {
                panic!("oh noes!");
            }
        }
    }
}

const CAPACITY: usize = 5;

struct Composite<Element> {
    data: [Element; CAPACITY],
}

impl<Element> Default for Composite<Element>
where
    Element: Default,
{
    fn default() -> Self {
        let mut temp: NoDrop<Self> = NoDrop::new(Self {
            data: unsafe { std::mem::uninitialized() },
        });

        unsafe {
            for index in 0..CAPACITY {
                std::ptr::write(&mut temp.data[index], Element::default());
            }
        }

        return temp.into_inner();
    }
}

impl<Element> From<[Element; CAPACITY]> for Composite<Element> {
    fn from(value: [Element; CAPACITY]) -> Self {
        return Self { data: value };
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let _v1: Composite<Dummy> = Composite::default();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=26cafbc53b68ceb069e0fa436c0973ba&version=stable&mode=debug)

It gets as far as ensuring uninitialized elements of the array don't call `drop`, but it doesn't yet allow for properly initialized components to call `drop` (they act like the uninitialized components and don't call `drop`).  I force the `Element::default()` call to generate a panic on a later element just to show the issue.

#### Actual output

Standard Error:

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (file:///playground)
Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.56 secs
 Running `target/debug/playground`
thread 'main' panicked at 'oh noes!', src/main.rs:19:17
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
```

Standard Output:

```
default
default
default
```

#### Intended output

Standard Error:

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (file:///playground)
Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.56 secs
 Running `target/debug/playground`
thread 'main' panicked at 'oh noes!', src/main.rs:19:17
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
```

Standard Output:

```
default
default
default
dropped
dropped
dropped
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell the Rust compiler to call drop on partially-initialized array elements when handling a panic?

**No**, but you can call `drop` yourself. You need to run code when a panic occurs.

#### Brute-force solution

This uses the building blocks of [`catch_unwind`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.catch_unwind.html), [`resume_unwind`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.resume_unwind.html), and [`AssertUnwindSafe`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/struct.AssertUnwindSafe.html) to notice that a panic occurred and run some cleanup code:

```
fn default() -> Self {
    use std::panic::{self, AssertUnwindSafe};

    let mut temp = NoDrop::new(Self {
        data: unsafe { std::mem::uninitialized() },
    });

    let mut valid = 0;

    let panicked = {
        let mut temp = AssertUnwindSafe(&mut temp);
        let mut valid = AssertUnwindSafe(&mut valid);

        std::panic::catch_unwind(move || unsafe {
            for index in 0..CAPACITY {
                std::ptr::write(&mut temp.data[index], T::default());
                **valid += 1;
            }
        })
    };

    if let Err(e) = panicked {
        for i in 0..valid {
            unsafe { std::ptr::read(&temp.data[i]) };
        }

        panic::resume_unwind(e);
    }

    temp.into_inner()
}
```

#### Slightly nicer

Once you recognize that a type's `Drop` implementation is run when a panic occurs, you can use that to your advantage by creating a *drop bomb* — a type that cleans up when dropped but in the success path it is not dropped:

```
extern crate nodrop;

use nodrop::NoDrop;

use std::{mem, ptr};

const CAPACITY: usize = 5;
type Data<T> = [T; CAPACITY];

struct Temp<T> {
    data: NoDrop<Data<T>>,
    valid: usize,
}

impl<T> Temp<T> {
    unsafe fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            data: NoDrop::new(mem::uninitialized()),
            valid: 0,
        }
    }

    unsafe fn push(&mut self, v: T) {
        if self.valid < CAPACITY {
            ptr::write(&mut self.data[self.valid], v);
            self.valid += 1;
        }
    }

    unsafe fn into_inner(mut self) -> Data<T> {
        let data = mem::replace(&mut self.data, mem::uninitialized());
        mem::forget(self);
        data.into_inner()
    }
}

impl<T> Drop for Temp<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            for i in 0..self.valid {
                ptr::read(&self.data[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Composite<T>(Data<T>);

impl<T> Default for Composite<T>
where
    T: Default,
{
    fn default() -> Self {
        unsafe {
            let mut tmp = Temp::new();

            for _ in 0..CAPACITY {
                tmp.push(T::default());
            }

            Composite(tmp.into_inner())
        }
    }
}

impl<T> From<Data<T>> for Composite<T> {
    fn from(value: Data<T>) -> Self {
        Composite(value)
    }
}

struct Dummy;

impl Drop for Dummy {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("dropping");
    }
}

impl Default for Dummy {
    fn default() -> Self {
        use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicUsize, Ordering, ATOMIC_USIZE_INIT};

        static COUNT: AtomicUsize = ATOMIC_USIZE_INIT;

        let count = COUNT.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
        if count < 3 {
            println!("default");
            Dummy {}
        } else {
            panic!("oh noes!");
        }
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let _v1: Composite<Dummy> = Composite::default();
}
```

Note that I've made some unrelated cleanups:

1. Using an atomic variable instead of `unsafe` static mutable variables.
2. Don't use `return` as the last statement of a block.
3. Converted `Composite` into a *newtype*, as `data` isn't a wonderful variable name.
4. Imported the `mem` and `ptr` modules for easier access.
5. Created the `Data<T>` type alias to avoid retyping that detail.

#### An elegant solution

The choice of `push` in the second solution is no accident. `Temp` is a poor implementation of a variable-sized stack-allocated vector. There's a *good* implementation called [arrayvec](https://crates.io/crates/arrayvec) which we can use instead:

```
extern crate arrayvec;

use arrayvec::ArrayVec;

const CAPACITY: usize = 5;
type Data<T> = [T; CAPACITY];

struct Composite<T>(Data<T>);

impl<T> Default for Composite<T>
where
    T: Default,
{
    fn default() -> Self {
        let tmp: ArrayVec<_> = (0..CAPACITY).map(|_| T::default()).collect();

        match tmp.into_inner() {
            Ok(data) => Composite(data),
            Err(_) => panic!("Didn't insert enough values"),
        }
    }
}
```

Would you be surprised to learn that nodrop was created in a large part to be used for arrayvec? The same author created both!

Comment: Thank you very much!  Two followup questions for my own info:
1.  Do .map() and .collect() not use heap allocation?  I've seen them used in context of collections, which typically do.

2.  In the std::mem::replace() call, I know that std::mem::uninitialized() doesn't do anything normally, but since it is passed in as a parameter, is another equally sized array created temporarily to pass into replace()?  Asking in case I have large arrays.

Comment: @Jere no, `map` and `collect` do not use the heap (why would they even need to?). They are [provided by libcore](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/iter/trait.Iterator.html), which doesn't even have access to an allocator. You can see the implementations of [`map`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.25.0/src/libcore/iter/mod.rs#L1308-L1310) and [`collect`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.25.0/src/libcore/iter/iterator.rs#L1302-L1304) to verify for yourself.

Comment: @Jere it is possible that the copying the uninitialized array may incur some overhead, but returning the array from the call to `default` may also require moving it, and every time you move the `Composite` has the same issue. The docs for [`ArrayVec::into_inner`](https://docs.rs/arrayvec/0.4.7/arrayvec/struct.ArrayVec.html#method.into_inner) mention some overhead, which I *assume* is referring to this.